# Prove that $A_1 \cdot B_1 + A_2 \cdot B_2 > A_1 \cdot B_2 + A_2 \cdot B_1$ for $0 < A_1 < A_2$ and $0 < B_1 < B_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, rearrangement-inequality

We are asked to prove or disprove that this is correct $A_1 \cdot B_1 + A_2 \cdot B_2 > A_1 \cdot B_2 + A_2 \cdot B_1$  for $0 < A_1 < A_2$ and $0 < B_1 < B_2$.

I'm not very experienced with writing such proofs, so I'm not sure how should I start, I'm more asking about hints how to write the proof, not really about full proof, however any help would be helpful.

Comment: it's equivalent to $A_2(B_2-B_1)>A_1(B_2-B_1)$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
0 < (A_2-A_1)(B_2-B_1)
$$
and expand the RHS

Answer (score 1):

Begin with these steps

1. Move all members to the left side
2. Make two pairs with common multiplier
3. Factor out that common multiplier

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to bring everything on one side and then show that the resulting term is greater than zero. In this case we get
$$A_1 \cdot B_1 + A_2 \cdot B_2- A_1 \cdot B_2 - A_2 \cdot B_1$$
We can bring the terms together as follows:
$$A_1 \cdot(B_1-B_2) + A_2\cdot (B_2- B_1)$$
and finally this is equal to
$$(A_1-A_2)(B_1-B_2)$$
which is greater than zero due to the assumptions ($-\cdot - =+$)